# Programmatically resize DataGridView to remove scroll bars

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a user definable number of columns (anywhere from ~6-60) of numerical data.  At the higher end that amount of data in the grid exceeds that which can be displayed on screen at once.  I have a graph that goes with the data.   I would like to keep the two in sync, so that a specific time T on the graph is in line vertically with the same time in the grid.

To do this I'd like to make the DGV just wide enough to avoid a horizontal scroll bar, have the graph be equally wide, and then offload the scrolling onto a container control.  However, I can't find a way to directly get the width I'd need to set the DGV to in order to remove the scroll bar from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent a DataGridView from displaying its horizontal scrollbar you'll need to make sure your DGV's width is not less than the width of its columns plus the row header's width.  You'll also need to adjust for the two pixels that are added to the control's width (and height) when its `BorderStyle` property is not `None`.

Here's a method which will return this minimum value for a given DataGridView:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the minimum width in pixels a DataGridView can be before the control's vertical scrollbar would be displayed.
/// </summary>
private int GetDgvMinWidth(DataGridView dgv) {
    // Add two pixels for the border for BorderStyles other than None.
    var controlBorderWidth = (dgv.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None) ? 0 : 2;

    // Return the width of all columns plus the row header, and adjusted for the DGV's BorderStyle.
    return dgv.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) + dgv.RowHeadersWidth + controlBorderWidth;
}
```

Comment: The vertical scrollbar isn't an issue in my case, but couldn't this be done less painfully than a subclass by adding up the vertical height of the rows and etc, and checking that against the control height?

Comment: @Dan, I believe I misunderstood your question.  Do you want to set your DGV's height so it never displays a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Not quite, I want it's width set so it never displays a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: The number of rows is fixed, so I can make sure it's always tall enough to avoid vertical scrolling.

Comment: Gave this a test, unfortunately checking on DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed doesn't work when adding columns.  The new columns won't be displayed because the older narrower grid will have them hidden to the right until scrolled.  As a result this method won't resize the grid to show them.

Comment: The correct constant to use is: DataGridViewElementStates.Visible

Comment: @Dan Didn't catch the DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed issue.  Updated my answer for future searchers.

Comment: this won't work when rows are added and a vertical scroll bar appears because the width of the vertical scroll bar is not accounted for.   Also it's worth mentioning why you used the number 2 for border.

Answer (score 3):

This will resize the columns to fit the space they are provided with and it will remove the horizontal scrollbar.

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode  = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

This will resize the columns to become the smallest possible width and still keep the values on the cells visible and it will automatically resize the datagridview to fit the columns, but the horizontal scrollbar may appear if the form is not big enough. In that case, you would have to resize the form's width.

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode  = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: That would also result in variable width columns, which is not acceptable since they need to match the spacing of the graph's horizontal scale.