# Can't get minimum datagridview width after changing font

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

This question hasn't been asked elsewhere here as it's particular to having changed font. And other answers have a solution that doesn't work after a font change.

The fix width button is meant to set the width of the datagridview so there are no scroll bars.

If I click  add row, then fix width then change font then fix width, then fix width doesn't work.  So to label them  A,B,C,D

A)add row         <-- WORKS
B)fix width  <---  WORKS
C)change font   <--- WORKS
D)fix width,  <--- FAILS

Fix width worked on line B, but fails on line D i.e. fails after the font change.

I have an alternative method to get the min width, that i've included, but neither of them are working.. So the width isn't getting set correctly.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dgvblah1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false; // maybe doesn't make a difference here for some reaosn. 

            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "Col1");
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

            /*
            btnaddrow.PerformClick();
            btnchangefont.PerformClick();
            btnaddrow.PerformClick();
            btnfixwidth.PerformClick(); //fail
            */

        }

        private int seeifworks_get_min_dgv_width_A(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            // it's not too bad, it sometimes makes it the correct width and sometimes not quite enough, and so it's worth then running the next method that increments the width until there are no more horizontal scroll bars.

            int padding = 2; // clearly wrong here, it seems
            int tw = dgv.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None) + dgv.RowHeadersWidth + padding + 2;
            int th = dgv.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.None) + dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight;

            return  tw;
        }

        private int seeifworks_get_min_dgv_width_B(DataGridView dgv)
        {
             // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651487/programmatically-resize-datagridview-to-remove-scroll-bars
            // Add two pixels for the border for BorderStyles other than None.
            var controlBorderWidth = (dgv.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None) ? 0 : 2;

            // Return the width of all columns plus the row header, and adjusted for the DGV's BorderStyle.
            return dgv.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) + dgv.RowHeadersWidth + controlBorderWidth;

        }


        private void btnfixwidth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  dataGridView1.Width = seeifworks_get_min_dgv_width_A(dataGridView1);

            dataGridView1.Width = seeifworks_get_min_dgv_width_B(dataGridView1);


        }

        private void btnaddrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
        }

        private void btnchangefont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Courier New", 30, FontStyle.Bold);

            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the vertical scollbar is not visible the method works properly, but if by changing fond and adding rows vertical scrollbar got visible, you should also add the width of scrollbar to calculated width of columns. Here is a better version of the method which calculates preferred width of `DataGridView`:

```
private int GetPreferredWidth(DataGridView grid)
{
    var border = 0;
    if (grid.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
        border = 2 * SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width;
    var vscrollWidth = 0;
    var vscroll = dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (vscroll != null && vscroll.Visible)
        border += vscroll.Width;
    var columnsWidth = grid.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
    var rowHeadersWidth = 0;
    if (grid.RowHeadersVisible)
        rowHeadersWidth = grid.RowHeadersWidth;
    return columnsWidth + vscrollWidth + rowHeadersWidth + border;  
}
```

Also `grid.GetPreferredSize(new Size(0, 0)).Width;` is a good option but it appends some extra width. If you don't mind that extra width, that extra size, you can the `GetPreferredSize` method.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that,  i'm curious how you figured out that it was the size of the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: It's not a guess, I tested your code, it worked properly. But in cases that vertical scrollbar appeared because of number of rows or large font, your method didn't worked properly. I changed it to above method and now it also works properly when having a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: great.. btw you missed rowheaderswidth(that's the weird column like thing before the first column),  I just added that. And you missed the 'n' in columns so I corrected that spelling error.

Comment: Good job! Thanks for the correction :) I also added a criteria to check if `grid.RowHeadersVisible` then add `grid.RowHeadersWidth`.

Comment: thanks, and where did you get about the `border = 2 * SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width;` ?  (like that the datagridview's fixed single border is two times the standard one or something? - where did you find that from?)

Comment: You're welcome. It comes from [SystemInformation.BorderSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.bordersize(v=vs.110).aspx). It's a system settings, but as far as I know usually it's 1 as you used in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118672/discussion-between-barlop-and-reza-aghaei).